# Tensorflow 2.4.1 - using tf.data.Dataset to fit a Keras Sequential Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to fit a `tf.data.Dataset` as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

INPUT_NEURONS = 10
OUTPUT_NEURONS = 1

features = tf.random.normal((1000, INPUT_NEURONS))
labels = tf.random.normal((1000, OUTPUT_NEURONS))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))

def build_model():

  model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(3, input_shape=[INPUT_NEURONS]),
        layers.Dense(OUTPUT_NEURONS),
    ]
  )

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

  return model

model = build_model()

model.fit(dataset, epochs=2, verbose=2)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the
> layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 10 but received
> input with shape (10, 1)

The `model.summary()` looks good though:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 3)                 33        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 4         
=================================================================
Total params: 37
Trainable params: 37
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Is [Keras Model `fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) actually suitable to `tf.data.Dataset`? If so, what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to batch it: `dataset.batch(batch_size)`.

Comment: @Frightera thanks for the comment. Could you explain why calling batch() is mandatory here? I understand what is batch but as far I know training using batches is optional, a hyperparameter to use or not during the model development. Right?

Comment: @Frightera is right (you should post it, I think).

Comment: More specifically, @Duloren should do `dataset = dataset.batch(3)` after slicing.

Comment: @M.Innat Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as far I know training using batches is optional, a hyperparameter to
> use or not during the model development

Not exactly, not optional. TF-Keras is designed to work with batches. First dimension in the summary always corresponds to `batch_size`, and `None` indicates that any `batch_size` is accepted by the model.

Most of the times you want your model to accept any batch size. Well, if you use `stateful` LSTMs then you want to a define static `batch_size`.

After you put your data into `tf.data.Dataset` they would not have batch dimension specifically:

```
dataset.element_spec
>> (TensorSpec(shape=(10,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
    TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

And when using `tf.data`, `batch_size` in `Model.fit()` is ignored, so batching should be done manually. More specifically, you may not know how many elements a `tf.data.Dataset` contains everytime.

In this situation it does not make sense (I'll explain) to batch after dataset creation:

```
dataset.batch(3).element_spec
>> (TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

`tf.data` is generally used with mid-large size datasets so `batching` it after creation will allow vectorized transformations. Consider these scenarios:

1. You have 5M rows of signal data want to apply fft. If you don't batch it before the the fft process, it will apply one by one.
2. You have (100K) images dataset. You want to apply some transformations or some operations. Batched dataset will allow faster and vectorized transformations and save a lot of time.