# using .from_tensor_slices to setup data for model fitting,Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Tensorflow newby here, trying to understand how the difference between different ways of accessing tensorflow model.fit. With the following setup

```
train_set=[[0.66,0.83,1.93],[0.74,0.79,1.53]...] #np.array shape (60,3)
labels=[0,1,1,...] #np.array shape (60,)

dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_set,labels))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5,activation='relu'),    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    
    loss_fn=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=loss_fn,metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(dataset,epochs=num_epochs) #error occurs here
```

I receive: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).
Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (3,)

However using

```
model.fit(train_set,labels,epochs=num_epochs) works.
```

Based on my understanding of the docs  what .from_tensor_slices should do is produce a set of 60 tuples with for example first element ([0.66,0.83,1.93],0). which model.fit should accept. What do I have to change to get the model to accept the dataset? Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673360/tensorflow-2-4-1-using-tf-data-dataset-to-fit-a-keras-sequential-model/70673700#70673700

Comment: Yes! @Frightera Accepted your answer there.